# Using Catel.MVVM (4.1.0) in Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, catel

AFAIK `Catel.MVVM` should work well with `Xamarin.Forms` projects, but it doesn't in my case.

While `Catel.Core (4.1.0)` package reference can be added without any issues, adding `Catel.MVVM (4.1.0)` leads to an error:

> You are trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   'portable-net45+win+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10', but the
>   package does not contain any assembly references or content files that
>   are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the
>   package author.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this issue. We will look into it, see https://catelproject.atlassian.net/browse/CTL-628 for the details.